# Creating a Custom Predicate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function, predicate

I am new to Lambda's and Delegates. I think my question may not be a good question but i am trying to write a simple Custom Predicate that act just like a Built-In Prediciate.

So i am going to share my Code: Please share with me that where i am going to make a mistake:

**Built-In Predicate Code Example:**

```
namespace Built_In_Predicate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> _ListOfPlayers = new List<string>()
            {
                "James Anderson",
                "Broad",
                "foo"
            };

            // Method 1. Predicate and Anonymous function.

            Predicate<string> _Predicate = delegate (string someString) { return someString.Length == 3; };

            string result = _ListOfPlayers.Find(_Predicate);

            Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Trying to Create a Custom Predicate (Code):**

```
namespace CustomPredicate
{
    class Program
    {
        // Delegate (Takes some string as a Input and return a Boolean.)
        public delegate bool CustomPredicate(string someString);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> _ListOfPlayers = new List<string>()
            {
                "James Anderson",
                "Broad",
                "foo"
            };

            //  Instance of CustomPredicate.
            CustomPredicate customPredicate = delegate (string someString) { return someString.Length == 3; };

            string result = _ListOfPlayers.Find(customPredicate); // its error.
        }
    }
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use a custom delegate, and why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Sweeper i am just practicing delegates .. that why

Comment: You can't pass a custom predicate _type_ to `List<T>.Find`. But a 'custom predicate' just means and instance of the `Predicate<T>` type containing your own logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegates cannot be implicitly converted to each other even if they have the same signature.

`Find` expects a `System.Predicate<T>` so you *have* to give it a `System.Predicate<T>`.

You can write your own `Find` method if you want to use your own `CustomPredicate`.

There are also ways to use your `customPredicate` variable in the call to `Find`:

```
_ListOfPlayers.Find(new Predicate<string>(customPredicate));
_ListOfPlayers.Find(customPredicate.Invoke);
```

Comment: Thanks )- that's what i wanted.... `customPreicate.Invoke` worked for me..

Comment: @Rehan.S Note that I would never write something like that in production code. There is simply no point in reinventing the `Predicate` delegate and using it this way. In fact, I would rather use a lambda expression here: `_ListOfPlayers.Find(x => x.Length == 3)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful suggestion...but on my side i don't know how to invoke the `customPredicate` that i have written..any that is acheived by your answer...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Find with something else as the type Predicate. But if you want your own delegate, you could call FirstOrDefault (System.Linq) and then use it.

```
    private delegate bool CustomPredicate (string t);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> _ListOfPlayers = new List<string>()
        {
            "James Anderson",
            "Broad",
            "foo"
        };

        // Method 1. Predicate and Anonymous function.

        CustomPredicate _Predicate = delegate (string someString) { return    someString.Length == 3; };

        string result = _ListOfPlayers.FirstOrDefault(x => _Predicate(x));
        Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: No... `FirstOrDefault` return `IEnumerable` and that's what i don't want...

Comment: No. It returns the string (or null string). I guess what you mean might be ".Where(..)" ?

Comment: Please look at the Intellisence...Did you see that...its giving back `IEnumerable`

Comment: Intellisense tells me: string IEnumerable<string>.FirstOrDefault. The first string is the result. the IEnumerable is the type to be applied on. If you check Intellisense for .Where you will see IEnumerable<string> IEnumerable<string>.Where